# jQuery - how to cut down repetition in code?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code, a large chunk of which is used over and over. Is there some way to cut this down so that there is not so much repetition?

```
        // first slider
    $("#slider").slider({

        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            $("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
            $("#amount").val(p[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
            var ccc = $("#pricec").val();
            var ddd = $("#priced").val();
            var eee = $("#pricee").val();
            var fff = $("#pricef").val();
            var ggg = $("#priceg").is(":checked") ? 100 : 0;
            var hhh = $("#priceh").is(":checked") ? 100 : 0;
            var iii = $("#pricei").is(":checked") ? 100 : 0;
            total.val(+1500 + +aaa + +bbb + +ccc + +ddd + +eee + +fff + +ggg + +hhh + +iii);
            var GBP = parseInt(total.val());
            var EUR = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "EUR"});
            var USD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "USD"});
            var CAD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "CAD"});
            var SGD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "SGD"});
            var AUD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "AUD"});
            var ZAR = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "ZAR"});
            EUR = (Math.round(EUR / 100) * 100);
            USD = (Math.round(USD / 100) * 100);
            CAD = (Math.round(CAD / 100) * 100);
            AUD = (Math.round(AUD / 100) * 100);
            SGD = (Math.round(SGD / 100) * 100);
            ZAR = (Math.round(ZAR / 100) * 100); 
            GBP = accounting.formatMoney(GBP, "GBP £ ", 0, ",", ".");
            EUR = accounting.formatMoney(EUR, "EUR € ", 0, ",", ".");
            USD = accounting.formatMoney(USD, "USD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            CAD = accounting.formatMoney(CAD, "CAD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            AUD = accounting.formatMoney(AUD, "AUD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            SGD = accounting.formatMoney(SGD, "SGD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            ZAR = accounting.formatMoney(ZAR, "ZAR R ", 0, ",", ".");
            $("#total").val(GBP);
            $("#totaleur").val(EUR);
            $("#totalusd").val(USD);
            $("#totalcad").val(CAD);
            $("#totalaud").val(AUD);
            $("#totalsgd").val(SGD);
            $("#totalzar").val(ZAR);
        }
    });

    // second slider
    $("#sliderb").slider({
        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#priceb").val(d[ui.value]);
            $("#amountb").val(b[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
            var ccc = $("#pricec").val();
            var ddd = $("#priced").val();
            var eee = $("#pricee").val();
            var fff = $("#pricef").val();
            var ggg = $("#priceg").is(":checked") ? 100 : 0;
            var hhh = $("#priceh").is(":checked") ? 100 : 0;
            var iii = $("#pricei").is(":checked") ? 100 : 0;
            total.val(+1500 + +aaa + +bbb + +ccc + +ddd + +eee + +fff + +ggg + +hhh + +iii);
            var GBP = parseInt(total.val());
            var EUR = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "EUR"});
            var USD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "USD"});
            var CAD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "CAD"});
            var SGD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "SGD"});
            var AUD = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "AUD"});
            var ZAR = fx.convert(GBP, {to: "ZAR"});
            EUR = (Math.round(EUR / 100) * 100);
            USD = (Math.round(USD / 100) * 100);
            CAD = (Math.round(CAD / 100) * 100);
            AUD = (Math.round(AUD / 100) * 100);
            SGD = (Math.round(SGD / 100) * 100);
            ZAR = (Math.round(ZAR / 100) * 100); 
            GBP = accounting.formatMoney(GBP, "GBP £ ", 0, ",", ".");
            EUR = accounting.formatMoney(EUR, "EUR € ", 0, ",", ".");
            USD = accounting.formatMoney(USD, "USD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            CAD = accounting.formatMoney(CAD, "CAD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            AUD = accounting.formatMoney(AUD, "AUD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            SGD = accounting.formatMoney(SGD, "SGD $ ", 0, ",", ".");
            ZAR = accounting.formatMoney(ZAR, "ZAR R ", 0, ",", ".");
            $("#total").val(GBP);
            $("#totaleur").val(EUR);
            $("#totalusd").val(USD);
            $("#totalcad").val(CAD);
            $("#totalaud").val(AUD);
            $("#totalsgd").val(SGD);
            $("#totalzar").val(ZAR);
        }
    });
```

This repeats 6 times for `slidera`, `sliderb`, `sliderc`, `sliderd`, `slidere`, `sliderf`. The only differences are in the first two lines of the function:

```
$("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
$("#amount").val(p[ui.value]);
```

Here, `t` and `p` are different (random) letters each time.

Comment: Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better on CodeReview than here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange Network, http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: For reference, `EUR €`, `USD $`, etc are redundant.  `EUR`, being a currency code, already denotes that this is a monetary value in euros -- though you'll very often see it after the amount.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Position_of_ISO_4217_code_in_amounts

Comment: For starters you might want to use actual variable names, not just repeated letters like `aaa` and `bbb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the `t` and `p` equivalents as data members to each slider ahead of time.

```
$("#slider").data('prices', p);
$("#slider").data('amounts', t);
$("#slidera").data('prices', q);
$("#slidera").data('amounts', u);
// etc.
```

and then reference that in your handler:

```
$("#slider, #slidera, #sliderb").slider({   // or use a shared class

        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            var prices = $(this).data('prices');
            var amounts = $(this).data('amounts');
            $("#price").val(prices[ui.value]);
            $("#amount").val(amounts[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            var bbb = $("#priceb").val();

            // ...
```

Comment: Thanks - what happens if the "max" property (outside the function) also needs to be changed for each? I tried to put `$("#slider").data("maxi", 4);` with the data members and then `var maxi $(this).data('maxi');` right before `value: "0"` but this created an uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token.

Comment: Putting it "right before 'value: 0'" would be bad; you're in the middle of an object, not in a function where code can run. You should just be able to use: `max: $(this).data(maxi)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, it gets rid of the syntax error but for some reason the number in the data member `"maxi"` doesn't apply to `max:`.

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect that's probably not going to work. `this` doesn't mean what we want at that point. You can always set individual `max` values after the main `slider()` call. See http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to embed more info in your HTML.

The script right now works with each box individually, and the boxes are rather dumb.  They don't have any part in what happens with them, and any change requires editing both the HTML and the script.  What if you were to add attributes to each element, instead, and the script went by those attributes to determine how stuff behaves?

Picture this:

```
<input type="number" class="price">
<input type="hidden" class="price" value="250">
<label><input type="checkbox" class="price_check" value="100"> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="price_check" value="100"> Option 2</label>

<input type="text" class="total">
<input type="text" class="total" data-currency="EUR">
<input type="text" class="total" data-currency="USD">
```

The inputs have a `class` that says that they're price fields.  (The checkboxes have a different attribute so they're easier to select and filter separately.)  And the outputs specify what currency they should be in.

Now, instead of having to mess with each element individually, we can pull in whole groups of them via the `class` attribute and do the same thing with each of them.

```
var total_amt = 1500;
$('input.price').add($('input.price_check').filter(':checked'))
    .each(function() { total_amt += parseInt(this.value); });


$('.total[data-currency]').each(function() {
    var unit = "GBP";

    var value = total_amt;
    if (this.hasAttribute('data-currency')) {
        unit  = this.getAttribute('data-currency');
        value = Math.round(fx.convert(value, {to: unit}) / 100) * 100;
    }
    this.value = accounting.formatMoney(value, unit, 0, ",", '.');
}
```

Now, if you want to add a price field, you can just add it in to the HTML and the script will do the right thing with it automatially.  Same with currencies (though you'll need to ensure that `fx` knows how to convert to the new currency).